# Javascript: how to open a url in new tab without knowing protocol

Tags: javascript, browser, href

In my javascript webapp I have a list of external urls, many of them are without protocol (because they are stored from users into the database).

I'd like to render an anchor element for each of them, within a new browser tab. If I don't specify the protocol the href attribute doesn't work as I need, since it's considered a relative url.

If I try to prepend to each url the protocol (http or https) I don't have any way to decide which is the right one (except executing some http head call, a solution which I'd like to avoid).

I've noticed that if I open a browser tab and I paste in the url bar the url without protocol, modern browsers automatically detect the protocol and everything works smooth.

Can I somehow replicate the browser behaviour, which is:

- open a new tab
- paste some url into the url bar
- open the url in the best way

Comment: The browser will default to http. It's then up to the server to decide if you should be sent to https. Exception: HSTS will make the browser default to https, but this happens automatically so your code can just default to http and the browser will handle it.

Comment: *"I've noticed that if I open a browser tab and I paste in the url bar the url without protocol, modern browsers automatically detect the protocol and everything works smooth."* Are you sure they're really doing that? Or are they defaulting to HTTP but then either A) Being redirected by the site to HTTPS, or B) Falling back to HTTPS when they get 404 for HTTP.

Comment: *"...because they are stored from users into the database..."* Your best bet is to validate the URLs on receipt and ensure that they're complete. A URL without protocol is incomplete.

Comment: I can't change the database, since it now has a hundred thousand links and I can't fix all of them.

Comment: You right, http works in all cases